# Chromecast GCKDiscoveryManager lists a device that does not exist for device selection dialog

Tags: ios, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm having an issue in an iOS app where a Chromecast receiver device still remains in the device selection list even after it has been removed from the network and/or powered off.

It typically shows the actually name of the disconnected device, but sometimes the chromecast dialog screen continues to list a device named "Guest Device" despite there not being other Chromecast devices connected to the network. When the user tries to connect to this device, they are unable to since the device does not actually exist.

It seems like  this is the same entry for the device that was removed from the network previously and is perhaps how the SDK handles this case.

I've tried calling the GCKDiscoveryManager::startDiscovery method whenever the device selection dialog is displayed, but the phantom device is still returned by the discoveryManager when calling deviceAtIndex or when checking deviceCount.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I've updated to SDK version 4.3.5

Is this an issue in the SDK itself or is there something else I can do to force a refresh?

Steps to reproduce:

- Ensure there is a Chromecast in the network ready to connect
- Launch App
- Disconnect the Chromecast from the network
- Wait for 5-10 seconds
- Tap the cast button in the app
- Note that disconnected device or "Guest Device" is still listed

Comment: Have you checked this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/hoHJMeM5Qns) regarding this issue? Most of the developers fixed their problem by restarting the router.

Comment: Thanks, yes we see this consistently on multiple networks, even after restarting routers, etc.

Comment: I have the same problem, you ever sorted this one out?